# MS Excel - is it possible to change from writeable to read-only?

Tags: microsoft-excel, read-only

I have a question if it is possible while using MS Excel spreadsheet to change how it's open from writeable to read-only without closing it?

I am working on the network file and sometimes when someone else in my room wants to access it as writeable I would like to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you open a file your computer locks it so your changes get saved over anyone else who may try to change it while you have it open. As far as I know, you cannot do as you described to switch which user gets to write to the file without closing the file.

**BUT** you may be able to use the shared workbook feature to allow collaboration of a networked file via multiple people.

> If you need input from several people, you can create a shared
>   workbook and place it on a network location where they can edit it
>   simultaneously.

Here [information](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-shared-workbooks-HP005262294.aspx) about shared workbooks.

Comment: It's not about choosing who should save changes. It's more about quick change from writeable mode to read-only mode.